# Using Sorting by distance from user location

Tags: android

I have an android app like a City directory that shows results sorted as Last Updated First.. I would like to change that to sort by distance from the user location.
New to this, need help pointing in the right direction...

Comment: Please be more specific about what you've tried so far to solve your problem.

Comment: New to StackOverflow too, Welcome, try to give a minimal, complete and verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Please use bellow sorting mechanism on user model class

Collections.sort(cityList, new Comparator(){

```
public int compare(City obj1, City obj2) {

    // cityList --> ArrayList<City>
    // obj1, obj2 are City objects and having location 
    // mLocation is user location 

    Location patent1 = new Location("hardcoded position");
    patent1.setLatitude(obj1.getLatitude());
    patent1.setLongitude(obj1.getLongitude());

    Location patent2 = new Location("hardcoded position");
    patent2.setLatitude(obj2.getLatitude());
    patent2.setLongitude(obj2.getLongitude());

    return mLocation.distanceTo(patent1) > mLocation.distanceTo(patent2) ? 1
            : mLocation.distanceTo(patent1) < mLocation.distanceTo(patent2) ? -1
            : 0;

}
```

});